# artifactory - get file date creation and modification from repo

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I tried to google didn't really get the result I was looking for.  Was wondering does any know how to get the date creation and date modification date of an artifact from artifactory?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, here are two -

To get the information on a specific file in Artifactory you can use the [File Info REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileInfo):

```
GET https://artifacotry.my.org/artifactory/api/storage/my-repo/path/to/some-file.txt

200
{
  "repo": "my-repo",
  "path": "path/to/some-file.txt",
  "created": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
  "lastModified": ISO8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ),
  ...
{
```

To execute a query (can be complex) to find files you can use [AQL (Artifactory Query Language)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)), just make sure to include the relevant fields in the result, e.g.:

```
POST https://artifacotry.my.org/artifactory/api/search/aql
items.find(
    {
        "repo":"my-repo"
    }
).include(
    "item.repo",
    "item.path",
    "item.name",
    "item.created",
    "item.updated"
)

200
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "repo" : "my-repo",
      "path" : "path/to",
      "name" : "some-file.txt",
      "created" : "2015-01-01T10:10:52.383+02:00",
      "updated" : "2015-01-01T10:12:25.182+02:00"
    }, 
    ...
  ], 
  ...
}
```